# diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs Is there any other way to write the breadcrumbs instead of writing it all into the breadcrumbs file/s?

Tags: php, laravel, breadcrumbs

I started with a few breadcrumbs for my routes following the docs

```
Create a file called routes/breadcrumbs.php that looks like this:

<?php

// Home
Breadcrumbs::for('home', function ($trail) {
    $trail->push('Home', route('home'));
});

// Home > About
Breadcrumbs::for('about', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push('About', route('about'));
});

// Home > Blog
Breadcrumbs::for('blog', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push('Blog', route('blog'));
});

// Home > Blog > [Category]
Breadcrumbs::for('category', function ($trail, $category) {
    $trail->parent('blog');
    $trail->push($category->title, route('category', $category->id));
});

// Home > Blog > [Category] > [Post]
Breadcrumbs::for('post', function ($trail, $post) {
    $trail->parent('category', $post->category);
    $trail->push($post->title, route('post', $post->id));
});
```

it's cool and it works... but I can't imagine writing all the breadcrumbs into that file if you have 100+ breadcrumbs

Seems like an anti pattern!?

Maybe someone uses this package and knows a solution on how to avoid writing all the breadcrumbs into single file like the docs say?

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of Laravel Breadcrumbs here.

[That's a common question.](https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs#why-is-there-no-breadcrumbsresource-method) The most elegant solution would be tapping into macros for resourceful routes.

```
Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title) {
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}.index"...
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}.create"...
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}.show"...
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}.edit"...
});
```

Then, you could use this shortcut like:

```
Breadcrumbs::resource('blog', 'Blog');
```

Hope that helps. Always open to ideas on how to improve the library. Feel free to start a discussion on GitHub, it's much easier to get on my radar that way!